# How to combine mgwt and mvp4g?

Tags: gwt, mvp, mvp4g, mgwt

Does anyone have experience integrating mvp4g into mgwt? As mgwt seems to offer specific ActivityManager/AnimationMapper implementations (see http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/GettingStarted) I wonder if you can get the same functionality in mvp4g?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mgwt with any mvp framework. It does not make any assumptions about it.

For Activities and Places in GWT though we have a special implementation.
If you want to use it with another MVP Framework use the AnimationHelper see:

http://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/HelloWorldExample